# ICS file - added URL is not showing in calender invitation

Tags: icalendar

I am building simple invitation using .ics files and sending through email.
Here is what it makes:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DESCRIPTION:Openmind Wellbeing Session Invitation
DTSTART:20190206T124807Z
DTEND:20190206T133707Z
SUMMARY:OpenMind: Lilla Douglas - Yoga F2f
URL:https://example.com/something/something
LOCATION:2825 safdsaf Ville dfad. 370\, Willland\, 20388-8233
DTSTAMP:20190215T121633Z
UID:5c66ada1a320e
ORGANIZER;CN=Effie:MAILTO:lind.eleonore@example.org
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Although it's working fine on Gmail and outlook.live. But unable to see the URL added here i.e. `https://example.com/something/something` (changed URL) in email or calender. 
Can anyone please Help and let me know if i am doing something wrong here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That maybe just what the applications you are using do .  May not be a way to influnce it, other than including the url (not html) as text in the DESCRIPTION.

Comment: Yeah @anmari, for now i have add URL in description. But its not the right way to do.
Even i haven't found any example where it showing how the URL will look like in invitation email when it is sent using `URL:` tag